# .net core 2.0 Azure AD Login Failing: AADSTS70001: Application with identifier 'xxx....' was not found in the directory 'xxxx....'

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc

Im trying to ad Azure AD login to my mvc web app. I have a web app already in azure and im trying to use an already established AD so that only them can connect to it. 
I want to try it locally first.

I followed a tutorial on pluralsight and on msdn aswell, but when I start the application it gives me the error from the headline on this post in microsoft.com.

If I start the app in incognito mode I get to input my mail, which prompts a logo from the right Active Directory on the password input. After passing the password I get the same error as the headline again. 
So it seems I atleast connect to the right AD.

I will post some pictures of the code and Azure, hope you can help!

I have registered my web app on the Active Directory and the registered web app properties looks like this. 
[image]

and the replyUrl:
[image]

then in the web app itself, in its authentication blade: 
[image]

and if you click active directory there: 
[image]
This is my Configure Services in Startup

```
         services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com";
                options.ClientId = "9174eb75-18eb-4857-86aa-XXXXXXXXX";
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
                options.CallbackPath = "/auth/signin-callback";
                options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44386/";
            })
            .AddCookie();
```

Comment: Hmm, it looks like you are adding auth yourself in the app as well as adding "Easy Auth" from the portal. Since you are adding it there yourself, you could try disabling the authentication from the portal. These both achieve the same thing, so you should not have them both enabled.

Comment: @juunas, huh, interesting. I turned off Authentication  web app itself, in its authentication blade: "App Service Authentication" and ran the application. Still get the same error..

Comment: Hmm, are you sure the application is registered in the AAD you are signing in to? I don't see why else the error would come up.

Comment: Its strange really.. I double checked, and yes, when I go in to the AAD and press 'App Registrations' i find my web app there with the correct app-id and so on. But I noticed when I get the error from the login the directory id ("not found in directory:XXXX") is not the same as the AAD-id that I am registered in! wtf..

Comment: Then the only logical explanation would be that the Authority you have defined is wrong

Comment: Yeah, but I only subscribe to that directory.. I have no idea whats going on. I'll keep you posted, and mark you as answer if it is as you said. Thanks...

Comment: @juunas, you are correct, it was the authority name that was wrong. They had a bunch of custom domain names on the AAD so I tried one of them( "XXX.com") instead of "XXX.onmicrosoft.com" and it works now. Thanks a bunch! If you make a post I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, you want to configure Azure App Service app to use Azure Active Directory login. You should register your web app in Azure AD. Then add Azure Active Directory information to Azure App Service app. For more details, please refer to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication).

Besides, if you want to try it in locally, you only should register your local web app in Azure AD. You do not need to add Azure Active Directory information to Azure App Service app. There is a [sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore/) for you.